# Restrict Bootstrap Modal to nested UI-View

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a page that has nested . I was wondering if I have a modal inside a child , can I have the modal backdrop restricted to just inside that , and therefore stuff in the parent  (such as a sidenav bar) accessible to click, and then stuff inside the child  still unable to click due to the modal backdrop?

Comment: Which modals are you using, angular-ui? If so, I don't think that's possible, as the backdrop element is just added to the end of the body element (I assume this is to help guarantee that the backdrop and modal are on top of everything else). 

However, this may be something you could post in their Issues on GitHub and it could potentially be added in a new release.

Comment: Sorry I am using Bootstrap 3.0 Modals

Comment: Ah, well angular-ui is built from Bootstrap 3.0 so I think the same rules apply. If you haven't checked out [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), you should totally check it out. They have Angular directives for almost all Bootstrap components (without jQuery!)